# how do i execute c=bin\jlogin -c "exit" $value |grep "Error" >>test

Tags: bash

how do i execute

```
c=bin\jlogin -c "exit" $value |grep "Error" >>test  in bash
```

i want to store the return value in c variable. $value contains some previously parsed data..i want to run the complete string as a command but when i run the shell i get an error

```
=bin\jlogin command not found.
```

kidly help me what is happening and how i can solve it! searched google but it does not show results which has such complexity like user defined variables
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `\j` means here, but I think what you are looking for is the backtick operator:

```
c=`((bin/jlogin -c "exit" $value ; echo $? >&3) | grep "Error" >> test) 3>&1)`
```

This will redirect the exit value of jlogin to handle 3 and then redirect it back to STDOUT, which will be copied to `$c`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do? :

```
/bin/jlogin -c exit "$value" | grep Error >>test
c=$?
```

That will run the command `/bin/jlogin -c exit "$value"`, piping its output to `grep Error >>test`. It will then set `$c` to `0` if the string `Error` was found, and to `1` if it was not.